Cron time zone won't work on an AWS based EC2 instance
I have an EC2 instance that runs linux. The timezone is set to UTC time and I need my cron tasks to work on UK timezone. However, I am unable to change the system clock to the UK timezone. It must remain in UTC.
I know I can use CRON_TZ=Europe/London, yet when I do so my command below will not run on the UK timezone. Only UTC.
CRON_TZ=Europe/London    
10 15 * * *  echo "$(date) This is UTC time!" > /tmp/utc.txt
10 15 * * * TZ=Europe/London echo "$(date) This is Europe/London time!" > /tmp/london2.txt

This occurs even if I put the timezone in the command line instead of at the top of the crontab file. I have restarted the cron server. I have edited the crontab file from root and from a specific user. I have even added the cron_tz variable at the start of each command. As shown below. Nothing is making cron trigger at the UK time.
* * * * * TZ=Europe/London echo "$(date) This is Europe/London time!" > /tmp/london2.txt
The only way to fix this is this:

UK time is 1 hour ahead of UTC time. When I change the system clock to November, the clocks in the UK go back 1 hour and are then equal to UTC time. This is the only time cron will run at the right time. Is there any way to make cron trigger at the UK time without having to worry about the clocks going forwards or back?

Do you have tzdata package installed on your VM? The TZ environment variable does not work without that.

The CRON_TZ and TZ variables affect the timezone in which the commands are executed. They do not alter the crontab scheduling.
You can change the timezone under which cron executes without adjusting the system time. Whether this is acceptable or not is up to you.
systemctl edit cron.service

In the empty section add a definition for your required timezone. Here's a partial view into the file being edited:
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/cron.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

[Service]
Environment=TZ=Europe/London

### Lines below this comment will be discarded

Now restart cron
systemctl restart cron.service

After this change, the cron schedule will be based on the specified timezone (Europe/London). HOWEVER, be aware that the jobs themselves will still run under the system timezone so if you need to change that you will also require a timezone setting either in the crontab file itself or per command entry:
TZ=Europe/London

You can undo the systemctl edit cron.service change:
systemctl revert cron.service
systemctl restart cron


Hi Chris, thank you for answering. Quick question, when I use the cron service command I'm getting this message "No files found for cron.service. " Could you advise?

What flavour (distribution and version) of Linux is your EC2 instance running?

NAME= Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
